# Is the relation {(2,3),(3,3),(4,2),(5,1)} a function with domain and co-domain {1,2,3,4,5}?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I got a question marked incorrect, however, searching around, I found that the general consensus was that I got the answer correct. I promise that I am not asking you to do my homework as it has already been graded, but I really need to know the truth if I am to learn anything.

The task was to decide whether a relation is a function.

The one I got wrong:

- Problem:

The domain and co domain are {1,2,3,4,5}  and the relation R is given by the set of ordered pairs:  {(2,3),(3,3),(4,2),(5,1)}.

- my answer was that is was a function - and it was marked as incorrect
- my instructor said that is was not a function because 1 does not have an associated value
- my response was that 5 had the associated value of 1 so it was still a function
- her response was that 5 was clearly in the co domain.

From what I can tell, no indication was given as to what values in the set were in the domain or in the co domain simply by this: {1,2,3,4,5}

Was I incorrect in my finding that 1 was not the domain but the co domain and that 5 was in the domain based on the information provided?

Comment: $1$ is in both the domain and the codomain.  Thus for this relation to be a function there must exist a tuple whose first entry is $1$.  Your teacher is correct.

Comment: Thank you.  I am willing to admin when I am wrong but I am driven to be sure.  This particular class is killing me.  Most of it reads like trick questions and that bothers my.  Add to that, the 'e books' for the class are horribly insufficient.  The entire section on domains and co domains was a mere 4 sentences.  Is there anywhere I can go to get more information for this?

Comment: you could try wikipedia

Comment: With regard to your point, "my response was that 5 had the associated value of 1 so it was still a function", note that the association moves forward, so to speak, because the relation is given by *ordered* pairs. So if $(a,b)$ is part of the relation $R$, then $a$ is associated with $b$, but it isn't necessarily true that $b$ is associated with anything.

Comment: Many people struggle with this type of math course because it is the first which involves more than computation. Be assured that your frustration is completely normal! It is also very common in mathematical writing that a paragraph's worth of content be squeezed into a few sentences - the expectation is that the reader will read each sentence slowly and carefully before moving on. In normal writing, if the reader gets confused they just keep reading and the writer will clarify it...math isn't like that. Just keep working at it, good luck

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You specified a function as follows: $$f(2)=3, f(3)=3, f(4)=2, f(5)=1$$

This is not completely defined on the domain, as $1$ is not sent anywhere.

If instead you misunderstood the usual way functions are defined, you might argue that you instead defined the function $$f(3)=2, f(3)=3, f(2)=4, f(1)=5$$
This would of course be wrong, but also still not be a function, because it does not send $5$ anywhere.

Also, in this problem, both domain and codomain are $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.

Answer (score 0):

A function, by definition, must be well defined and defined everywhere. Here the problem is with the later. Your relation is not defined everywhere.

A relation $\sim$ is defined everywhere if every element in the domain set is related to at least one element in the codomain.

i.e. $\forall x\in D \ \exists y\in C \ s.t. \ (x,y)\in R$ where $R$ is the relation, $D$ is the domain, and $C$ is the codomain.